# I am trying to align right my image using bootstrap4 but it is not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to align my image on the right, but it is not working.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="media">
    <img class="d-flex mr-3 img-thumbnail float-right" src="https://picsum.photos/200/100" alt="grand-buffet">
    <div class="media-body">
       <h2 class="mt-0">Weekend Grand Buffet <span class="badge badge-danger">NEW</span></h2>
       <p class="d-none d-sm-block">Featuring mouthwatering combinations with a choice of five different salads, six enticing appetizers, six main entrees and five choicest desserts. Free flowing bubbly and soft drinks. All for just $19.99 per person </p>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `order-1` to `img` (Build-in `property` = minimal code):

> Change the order of content in media objects by modifying the HTML
>   itself, or by adding some custom flexbox CSS to set the order property
>   (to an integer of your choosing).
>   https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/media-object/#order

`.order-1` CSS:

```
.order-1 {
    -ms-flex-order: 1;
    order: 1;
}
```

> Change the visual order of specific flex items with a handful of order
>   utilities. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/flex/#order

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="media">
    <img class="ml-3 img-thumbnail order-1" src="https://picsum.photos/200/100" alt="grand-buffet">
    <div class="media-body">
       <h2 class="mt-0">Weekend Grand Buffet <span class="badge badge-danger">NEW</span></h2>
       <p class="d-none d-sm-block">Featuring mouthwatering combinations with a choice of five different salads, six enticing appetizers, six main entrees and five choicest desserts. Free flowing bubbly and soft drinks. All for just $19.99 per person </p>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `float-right` with `ml-auto` in your img tag like below:

```html
<div class="media">
    <img class="d-flex img-thumbnail ml-auto" src="img/buffet.png" alt="grand-buffet">
    <div class="media-body">
       <h2 class="mt-0">Weekend Grand Buffet <span class="badge badge-danger">NEW</span></h2>
       <p class="d-none d-sm-block">Featuring mouthwatering combinations with a choice of five different salads, six enticing appetizers, six main entrees and five choicest desserts. Free flowing bubbly and soft drinks. All for just $19.99 per person </p>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by replacing mr-3 with ml-3 and float-right with order-3

Visit the following link for further details
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/flex/#order

Comment: Next time please add a comment (This is not "answer"). I guess you want to comment on my answer (I don't know if you got permission).